# preg_match with dot matches non-dot too

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to match `.com` (along with `word` and `@`) with preg_match like this:

```
if(preg_match("/(word|.com|\@)/i", $content)){
   // dance here
}
```

The problem is it matches the word `completely` for example, too. It should only match `.com`. How do I fix that?

Comment: Use [anchors](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php), e.g. `^` and `$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is a wildcard for "any single character". Since you watch to match a literal `.`, you have to escape it:

```
if(preg_match("/(word|\.com|\@)/i", $content)){
                      ^---
```